# Excel Date Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Need help with a complex formula that I cant seem to get right:

The data looks like this:

```
        A          B               C       D       E

1                                 2014    2015    2016
2    5/1/2014  7/1/2016            8       12      7
```

The formula needs to calculate the number of months for the given year in C1-E1 for example based upon the start and end dates A2/B2.

So in the starting year of 2014, there are 8 total months (May-Dec), 12 months for 2015 as the start and end date spans 2015 and for 2016, since the end date ends that year, how many months from the beginning of the year to the end date.

I can get part of the answer but cant figure it all out.  Please save me! :)

Comment: Your question is not that much clear. Are you going to achieve how many months spread in an year if month is greater than 12 based on start date and end date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will accomplish your objective, with a few assumptions:

1. Only whole months will be considered in A and B (for example, there will be no differentiation between 5/1/14 and 5/10/14 - they will both be considered as *May*.
2. Your example listed above is invalid: column E should show *6*, not 7, as there are only 6 months between 1/1/16 and 7/1/16.

Paste the following code into `C2` and drag it into `C2:E2`:

```
=IF(YEAR($A$2)<C$1,IF(YEAR($B$2)<C$1,0,IF(YEAR($B$2)>C$1,12,MONTH($B$2)-1)),IF(YEAR($A$2)>C$1,0,IF(YEAR($B$2)<C$1,0,IF(YEAR($B$2)>C$1,13-MONTH($A$2),MONTH($B$2)-MONTH($A$2)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that 7 is correct for 2016 in your example because you are counting any part of a month as a month, in which case you can use this formula in C2 copied across and down if required

`=IFERROR(MIN(DATEDIF(MAX($A2-DAY($A2)+1,DATE(C$1,1,1)),MIN($B2,DATE(C$1+1,1,0)),"m")+1,12),0)`

Comment: That's it!  Just need to add if any portion of a month is within the dates then count it.  The last poster added that.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using your provided example such that the worksheet looks like this:

[image: tigeravatar example]

In cell C2 and copied right is this formula:

```
=IF(YEAR($A2)=C$1,13-MONTH($A2),IF(YEAR($B2)=C$1,MONTH($B2),IF(OR(YEAR($A2)>C$1,YEAR($B2)<C$1),0,12)))
```

Comment: You sir are brilliant!  That is precisely what it should do.  I cannot thank you enough.  I did want to assume that any portion of a month was a full month.